# Synapse HTTP Linked Service fails

Tags: http, azure-synapse, http-redirect

Is there a way to allow redirects in an HTTP Linked Service in Synapse?

I have an HTTP Linked Service pointed to a simple URL.  The connection tests ok.  Setting up the Source for the Copy Activity fails with a 400 Bad Request.

I tested the HTTP connection in PostMan, and it connects ok, showing csv data.
But - if I disallow Redirects the PostMan connection fails, telling me it cannot access the URL or file on AWS.  The URL I set was not AWS, so I'm pretty sure it is a redirect.

Can redirects be enabled in this type of connector on Synapse?  Are they off by default?